# append the column in another text file

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, awk

Hii i have a text file having 3 column

```
2.0  44.8  789.3 
3.0  58.4  453.0
4.0  97.2 -489.1
5.2  35.3  458.6
```

i want to select the columns from the above text file and want to append the selected column in another text file .The file where i want to append the above columns are given below

```
> > > > 
    10.0    8.5
    20.0    8.5
    30.0    8.5
    40.0    8.5
> > > >
    10.0    8.0
    20.0    8.0
    30.0    8.0
    40.0    8.0
> > > >
    10.0    9.0
    20.0    9.0
    30.0    9.0
    40.0    9.0
> > > >
```

and my expected output is

```
> > > > 
    10.0    8.5   2.0
    20.0    8.5   3.0
    30.0    8.5   4.0
    40.0    8.5   5.2
> > > >
    10.0    8.0   44.8
    20.0    8.0   58.4
    30.0    8.0   97.2
    40.0    8.0   35.3
> > > >
    10.0    9.0   789.3
    20.0    9.0   453.0
    30.0    9.0  -489.1
    40.0    9.0   458.6
> > > >
```

i tried the script but after that not getting more idea, i need experts help.Thanks in advance.

```
 #!/bin/sh
 for file in inp.txt
 do
 awk '{print $1}' > colone
 done
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Your script has some syntax errors, please kindly check it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Good that you have shown your attempts in your question. Could you please explain on logic of appending columns into the new file more in your question for better understanding please.

Comment: yes for my work purposes i am trying to do it

Comment: @lijun, As mentioned in previous comment too, could you please do add logic of how to append column(eg on which lines or line numbers etc?) in your question, to make it more clear.

Comment: yes, first column will be appended to first block, then second column will be appended to second block etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    for (numBlocks=1; numBlocks<=NF; numBlocks++) {
        vals[numBlocks,NR] = $numBlocks
    }
    next
}
/^>/ {
    blockNr++
    rowNr = 0
    print
    next
}
{ printf "%s %7s\n", $0, vals[blockNr,++rowNr] }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
> > > >
    10.0    8.5     2.0
    20.0    8.5     3.0
    30.0    8.5     4.0
    40.0    8.5     5.2
> > > >
    10.0    8.0    44.8
    20.0    8.0    58.4
    30.0    8.0    97.2
    40.0    8.0    35.3
> > > >
    10.0    9.0   789.3
    20.0    9.0   453.0
    30.0    9.0  -489.1
    40.0    9.0   458.6
> > > >
```

Comment: can u please suggest where to give input in ur script

Comment: I show where to provide input - `awk -f tst.awk file1 file2`. If you'd rather not save the awk script in a file you can just put it between single quotes on the command line `awk 'script' file1 file2`.

Answer (score 3):

Based on OP's shown samples, could you please try following. This will print reset value of count after 3rd occurrence of `> >` in text file and again starts printing from 1st column values onwards from Input_file.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    value[FNR,i]=$i
  }
  next
}
/^> >/{
  count=0
  print
  if(col==3){ col=0 }
  col++
  next
}
{
  print $0"    "value[++count,col]
}
' Input_file text_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                       ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                    ##Checking condition FNR==NR when Input_file is being read.
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){       ##Traversing through all fields here. 
    value[FNR,i]=$i         ##Creating value with index of FNR,i here with value $i
  }
  next                      ##next will skip all further statments from here.
}
/^> >/{                     ##Checking condition if line starts from > > then do following.
  count=0                   ##Nulliffying count here.
  print                     ##Printing current line.
  if(col==3){ col=0 }       ##Checking if col is 3 then make its value 0 here. Why because OP sample has only 3 blocks and
                            ##if there are more than 3 then it will start printing from very 1st values onwards after every 3 blocks.
  col++                     ##Increasing value of col with 1 here.
  next                      ##next will skip all further statments from here.
}
{
  print $0"    "value[++count,col]  ##Printing current line with space and array value here.
}
' Input_file text_file      ##Mentioning Input_file and text_file names here.
```

Comment: its working fine but can we add more space among the columns

Comment: @lijun, I believe you meant less spaces, I have fixed it now, we should get output in same space format what text file already has. Please do let me know how it goes now?

Comment: can ur script would work, if i have more columns in text file

Comment: @lijun, I don't think so, answers will be given as per questions. So please don't change your base question now. You could test this answer with your given samples and could try to play around with it, if you have question then you could create a new question with your efforts in forums please. But changing base question's requirement is not recommended on SO, cheers.